# How to generate an ArrayList with li in html through the Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html-lists

I'm trying to make a list working with li in html, I already have the list running, but I need this to be generated automatically through the data obtained in Firebase...

This is the reference in Firebase

```
firebase.database (). ref (). child ("Users"). orderByChild ("Number");
```

This is the way I generated the list

```
var options = [
        set0 = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'],
        set1 = ['First Option', 'Second option', 'Third option']
    ];

function makeUL (array) {

    var list = document.createElement ('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i <array.length; i ++) {

        var item = document.createElement ('li');


        item.appendChild (document.createTextNode (array [i]));


        list.appendChild (item);
    }


    return list;
}

document.getElementById ('foo'). appendChild (makeUL (options [0]));
```

How could I join firebase with this list that I am generating, instead of manually putting the data in the var options, doing it through the data I want to obtain in Firebase.

I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: To learn how to read data from Firebase, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: I know how to read and write in firebase, but of html and javascript I know very little, I don't know how to create an array that generates a list in html with li and with the data of firebase

Comment: The `makeUL` code you shared does precisely that: creating an HTML list in code out of a list of values. Now just read those value from Firebase, and you're on your way.